# Getting TypeError: require.exec is not a function error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am facing this error. Following are the details when the error occurs on Magento 2.2.4

1. Created a custom module page.
2. Removed every block from custom module page except content block.
3. In other page wrote a $.get to pull the custom page via ajax.
4. Finally trying to add the result received from the $.get call to a div using $("#mydiv").html(result);
5. And $("#mydiv").html(result); statement is where the error is occurring.(although the content gets added but due to error further processing halts)

Any solution will be appreciated.